# Call action on page loading in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angular code:

```
application.controller('ImageController', function ImageController($scope, ImageService, ngDialog) {
  $scope.open = function (image) {
    ngDialog.open({
      className: 'modal',
      plain: false,
      scope: scope,
      template: 'image'
    });
  }
};
```

On page loading, when the url has the parameters source and key:

```
http://www.google.pt/?source=1&key=sdfd-sd-sf
```

I would like to call open and pass an image with:

```
image.source = 1;
image.key = sdfd-sd-sf;
```

How can I do this?

**UPDATE**

I tried to use ngroute:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/:source?/:key?',
  {
    controller: "ImageController"
  }
)
```

with the following route:

```
domain.com/?source=ddf&key=23jf-34j
```

On ImageController I tried to get the parameters source and key using:

```
var image = { source: $routeParams.source, key: $routeParams.key };
if (image.source != null && image.key != null) {
  open(image);
}
```

But both source and key are undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you using ngRoute?

Comment: @Shomz Yes, I am now. But I am not able to get the parameters. I just updated my code ... No idea why both parameters are undefined.

Comment: Your `when` is wrong, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I followed your example and just added the ? because the parameters are optional ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura your url should be `domain.com#/ddf/23jf-34j` as you mentioned the route

Comment: Yes, but i need opcional para meter alter ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ngRoute`, you can inject [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) into your controller and simply do:

```
image.source = $routeParams.source;
image.key = $routeParams.key;
```

Nice egghead video about it: https://thinkster.io/egghead/routeparams-api/

---

UPDATE

There's no need to specify query parameter names in `when` (it's only needed when using paths like `domain.com/source/123/key/456`), so this is wrong:

```
.when('/:source?/:key?',
```

It should be just:

```
.when('/',
```

While your URL has the hashbang (or html5mode):

```
domain.com/#/?source=ddf&key=23jf-34j
```

then this will work just fine:

```
var image = { source: $routeParams.source, key: $routeParams.key };
```

Note that if you're not using `ng-view` the parameters won't be available due to their async nature, so you need to use this watcher in your controller:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    console.log($routeParams);
});
```

or, if you inject `$route` instead of `$routeParams`, you can use:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    console.log($route.current.params);
});
```

it will return the same object.

---

UPDATE 2

After a little research, seems like by far the easiest way to do it is to inject `$location` service, and simply use:

```
var params = $location.search();
var image = { source: params.source, key: params.key };
```

Here is a simple example with html5 mode on (will work with your original URL): http://run.plnkr.co/sElZhTrI4JvGc0if/?source=SomeSrc&key=SomeKey

And the full Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jxol8e7YaghbNScICHqW